# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression when I execute my sql

Tags: sql, oracle

When I execute my SQL, I get the below error:

My exception is:

```
[SQL]select bd.name aaa   
from bd_material_v m ,bd_marbasclass bd  
where m.creator='1001A210000000000IIQ'  
and bd.code=substr(m.code,0,4)    
group by bd.name    
order by substr(m.code,0,4)  
[Err] ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

My SQL is below:

```
select bd.name aaa 
  from bd_material_v m ,bd_marbasclass bd
    where m.creator='1001A210000000000IIQ'
      and bd.code=substr(m.code,0,4)  
      group by bd.name 
      order by substr(m.code,0,4)
```

---

**Addtional**

If I annotation this line `group by bd.name`, I will query out the result, without the issue.

**EDIT**

My table:

`bd_marbasclass`

[image]

`bd_material_v`

[image]

---

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward - `aaa` isn't a group by expression. Can you share your table structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik Sure, I will, a minate

Comment: As an aside, please learn how to use `JOIN`. That old style join was phased out more than 10 years ago

Comment: You can find many, many answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+not+a+group+by+expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use select distinct instead:

```
select distinct bd.name aaa , 
       substr(m.code,0,4) -- see below code comment, either include this or remove the order by
from bd_material_v m
inner join bd_marbasclass bd
      on bd.code=substr(m.code,0,4)  
where m.creator='1001A210000000000IIQ'
order by substr(m.code,0,4) -- As this is oracle, you can only order by selected columns/expressions :D
```

Comment: thank you , but I got a error:`not a SELECTed expression`

Comment: This is what I would do as well as there is no need of a `group by` here. Not sure why this answer didn't got upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are ordering by something that is not in your `group by` clause.

For example, this works

```
SQL> with testGroup as ( select 1 as one, 2 as two from dual)
  2  select one
  3  from testGroup
  4  group by one;

       ONE
----------
         1
```

If you `order by` a column that is not in your `group by` clause:

```
SQL> with testGroup as ( select 1 as one, 2 as two from dual)
  2  select one
  3  from testGroup
  4  group by two;
select one
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

If you edit the `group by` clause to handle the column you need in the `order by`:

```
SQL> with testGroup as ( select 1 as one, 2 as two from dual)
  2  select one
  3  from testGroup
  4  group by one, two;

       ONE
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your join syntax is unconventional, the problem in your code is `order by`. Remove it and you will not get the `not a group by` error.

But I strongly suggest to correct the join syntax. use `inner join` on appropriate column.

```
select bd.name aaa 
  from bd_material_v m ,bd_marbasclass bd
    where m.creator='1001A210000000000IIQ'
      and bd.code=substr(m.code,0,4)  
      group by bd.name
```

So this will not give you error

```
with tbl(col1,col2) as 
(select 1,1 from dual union all
select 1,3 from dual )
select col1 as col1 
from tbl 
group by col1
```

But this will

```
with tbl(col1,col2) as 
(select 1,1 from dual union all
select 1,3 from dual )
select col1 as col1 
from tbl 
group by col1
order by col2
```

Comment: It's not unconventional, it's obsolete, ancient